# Dart: NoSuchMethodError - method not found "h" on null

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, dart-html

I am using Flutter Web and when accessing a FutureBuilder I get the NoSuchMethodError - method not found "h" on null
When inspecting the page, i see the following error:

```
core_patch.dart:195 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'h')
    at Object.bax (VM5 main.dart.js:25360:16)
    at VM5 main.dart.js:45250:25
    at aWT.a (VM5 main.dart.js:3607:62)
    at aWT.$2 (VM5 main.dart.js:39703:14)
    at aVB.$1 (VM5 main.dart.js:39697:21)
    at a8Y.nJ (VM5 main.dart.js:40765:32)
    at aN8.$0 (VM5 main.dart.js:40122:11)
    at Object.Ds (VM5 main.dart.js:3740:40)
    at ax.tk (VM5 main.dart.js:40054:3)
    at a3F.dm (VM5 main.dart.js:39692:8)
```

It looks like an error from Dart js.
I have update my flutter version to 2.10, but previously I had the same error, except that instead of "h" I got "i" (NoSuchMethodError - method not found "i")

**P.S.** I get this error ONLY in production(release) build, using debug build everything works just fine.

Code Snipped

```
FutureBuilder(
 future: AlgoliaService().getEmployees(searchQuery),
 builder: (BuildContext context, 
    AsyncSnapshot<AlgoliaQuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
             return Text("Error:  ${snapshot.error}"); // Error happens here
           }
    
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);}
```

Comment: try to install the package globally : npm i -g dart-sass                                                                    
`code` dart-sass assets/sass/main.scss
body {
  font: 100% Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #333333;
}

Comment: Maybe post your code?

Comment: Sure, I have added the code portion

Comment: I think it's related to algolia package, check : https://github.com/knoxpo/dart_algolia/issues/85

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71191080/13119969).

In case anyone is looking for an immediate fix, what worked for me was to force the use of 1.0.2 dependency instead of 1.0.4:

```
dependencies:
    algolia: '1.0.2'
```

This is an [open issue](https://github.com/knoxpo/dart_algolia/issues).

Answer (score 0):

You have to add checks like snapshot.hasData, snapshot.hasError in the builder method of FutureBuilder. Because at first the snapshot will always be null on a FutureBuilder and after the future is executed it will return value in snapshot.
Check this page there is a runnable example in here of [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The error "NoSuchMethodError - method not found "h" on null" is precisely inside the if(snapshot.hasError) {} block. More interestingly is that I do get the error only in production build, the debug one seems to work perfectly.