# Flutter Web release mode cannot show data from Algolia

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, algolia

I cannot show a list retrieved by Algolia when I am using --release mode in Flutter. It's very interesting that it works just fine when running the app in Flutter Web Debug.
Can anyone help me out with this issue?

Works with:

[✓] Flutter Web Debug

[✓] Postman

Error I got in Web Console:

```
js_helper.dart:1137 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'h')
    at Object.bf4 (VM939 main.dart.js:27309:16)
    at VM939 main.dart.js:52638:25
    at b_W.a (VM939 main.dart.js:5429:62)
    at b_W.$2 (VM939 main.dart.js:46761:14)
    at aZB.$1 (VM939 main.dart.js:46755:21)
    at abu.oj (VM939 main.dart.js:47823:32)
    at aQY.$0 (VM939 main.dart.js:47180:11)
    at Object.EG (VM939 main.dart.js:5562:40)
    at av.u7 (VM939 main.dart.js:47112:3)
    at a64.dj (VM939 main.dart.js:46750:8)
```

Flutter Version (Channel stable, 2.10.0, on macOS 12.1 21C52 darwin-x64, locale en-US)

Snipped code:
Algolia call function:

```
Future<AlgoliaQuerySnapshot> getEmployee(String name) async {
    AlgoliaQuery query = algolia.instance
        .index(employeeIndexName)
        .facetFilter('companyId:${userController.user.companyId}')
        .query(name);
    AlgoliaQuerySnapshot snap = await query.getObjects();
    return snap;
  }
```

Reveal in list:

```
FutureBuilder(
              future: AlgoliaService().getEmployee(searchQuery),
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<AlgoliaQuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('Something went wrong');
                }

                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
               return Text("No errors");
             )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue.

In case anyone is looking for an immediate fix, what worked for me was to force the use of 1.0.2 dependency instead of 1.0.4:

```
dependencies:
    algolia: '1.0.2'
```

This is an open [issue](https://github.com/knoxpo/dart_algolia/issues).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the issue on Github. Switching to 1.0.2 did not solve it for me

Answer (score 0):

If you're still struggling with this, you might want to try the officially supported approach of "rolling your own" platform channel using the Algolia Kotlin API client.

Instructions are here:
https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/getting-started/how-to/flutter/android/#prepare-your-project